# Unavailability of NAPA tool

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

NAPA tool  has been fully retired and its not available in office 365 environment but alternative is we can still build App using VS.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx

Is there any way to create SharePoint Hosted app in Office 365 without installing anything on our local machine.

Thanks in advance!!!